# File Reference Expired Error python telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

Everything works at least good at start and few hours later, but at some moment gets this error

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FileReferenceExpiredError: The file reference has expired and is no longer valid or it belongs to self-destructing media and cannot be resent (caused by SendMediaRequest)

This is how i clone messages from one telegram channel to another

```
posts = bot.get_messages(channel_from_entity, min_id=start_id - 1, max_id=999999,
                         filter=types.InputMessagesFilterEmpty())[::-1]
for post in posts:
    bot.send_message(channel_to, post)
    logger.info(f'Successfully posted | ID: {post.id}')
    time.sleep(POST_INTERVAL)
```

Maybe it seems to file_reference error, but i have no idea how to implement it.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should refetch resource's `file_reference`, because it expired.

[Docs](https://core.telegram.org/api/file_reference).